# Reduce the name of a ASCII

Tags: arcpy

I have to use a script to convert AscII to Raster, and I used one I found from GeoNet. But now, the problem is to reduce the name of the AscII files, because I can't name the Raster with more than 13 characters.

**MDT05-0561-H30-LIDAR.asc** is the name of files, and then, without changing the ".asc", because there is a looping reading this part, how can I reduce the formentioned name to "MDT05-0561.asc" name?

```py
import arcgisscripting, os

# Create the Geoprocessor 
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

# Set local variables 
InAsciiFile = None 
inDir = "" 
OutRaster = "" 
gp.outputCoordinateSystem = "etrs_89_wkd.prj"


for InAsciiFile in os.listdir(inDir):
    InAsciiFile =list(InAsciiFile)
    InAsciiFile.remove('-H30-LIDAR') 
#because all of them have the last part: -H30-LIDAR

if InAsciiFile.rsplit(".")[-1] == "asc":
     print InAsciiFile
   # Process: ASCIIToRaster_conversion
    gp.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(os.path.join(inDir,InAsciiFile), os.path.join(OutRaster,InAsciiFile.rsplit(".")[0]), "FLOAT")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use slicing to extract the first 10 characters, and the `os.path.splitext` function to append the original extension:

`OutAsciiFile = InAsciiFile[:10] + os.path.splitext(InAsciiFile)[1]`

This method will work without looking for a specific string.

Comment: In which line of code should I type that code? I put it after gp.outputCoordinateSystem so that it takes the global variable, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `replace` method on the string:

```
>>> s
'MDT05-0561-H30-LIDAR.asc'

>>> s.replace("-H30-LIDAR","")
'MDT05-0561.asc'
```

Comment: Ah, you are replacing the string with a "gap". I haven't thought about that... Thank you!

Comment: Of course, I have to delete "InAsciiFile =list(InAsciiFile)"